# Twilio Video Call Camera light remains On after disconnecting

Tags: twilio

I have integrated the Twilo video into my web application and it seems to be working fine the only issue im facing is that the camera light is still on even when we disconnect from the call i have attached my java script file along with this ticket if you could take a look at it it would be great Im using Twilio version 2.17.0

the camera light is still on even when we disconnect from the call i have attached my java script file along with this ticket if you could take a look at it it would be great Im using Twilio version 2.17.0